# How to reverse the keyframe?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I tried to create responsive web app, that looks on mobile as following:

[image]

By clicking on the menu bar it will transform to:

[image]

The style is written in SCSS and looks as following:

```
.topbar-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;

  .topbar-navi-menu {
    margin-left: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 40px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;

    i {
      position: absolute;
      height: 5px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #ffffff;

      &.topbar-animate-forward {
        &:first-child {
          animation: topbar-first-bulk 500ms forwards;
        }

        &:nth-child(2) {
          animation: topbar-middle-bulk 500ms forwards;
        }

        &:last-child {
          animation: topbar-last-bulk 500ms forwards;
        }
      }

      &:first-child {
        top: 0;
      }

      &:nth-child(2) {
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
      }

      &:last-child {
        bottom: 0;
      }
    }

    @keyframes topbar-first-bulk {
      0% {
        top: 0;
        transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
      }

      25% {
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
      }

      50% {
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
      }

      100% {
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
      }
    }

    @keyframes topbar-middle-bulk {
      0% {
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
      }

      25% {
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
      }

      50% {
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
      }

      100% {
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
      }
    }

    @keyframes topbar-last-bulk {
      0% {
        bottom: 0;
        transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
      }

      25% {
        bottom: 50%;
        transform: translateY(50%) rotate(0deg);
      }

      50% {
        bottom: 50%;
        transform: translateY(50%) rotate(-45deg);
      }

      100% {
        bottom: 50%;
        transform: translateY(50%) rotate(-45deg);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using [reasonreact](https://reasonml.github.io/reason-react/) it is like reactjs. The JSX struture:

```
<div className="topbar-container">
  <section className="topbar-menu">
    <a
      onClick={
        _evt => self.send(MobileMenuToggler(self.state.showMobileMenu))
      }
      className="topbar-navi-menu">
      <i className={self.state.mobileMenuAnimate} />
      <i className={self.state.mobileMenuAnimate} />
      <i className={self.state.mobileMenuAnimate} />
    </a>
  </section>
</div>
```

How to reverse the animation back to menu bar with css?

Comment: If this is changing between an open and close state, you should use a transition and not an animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a transition for swapping between states.  You can't tell animations to go forwards and backwards easily because their interpolation value, the current timestep at which the animation on, is sort of fixed.  Even if you suddenly told a style that it should be backward instead of forward, it wouldn't animate the way you would think because it will just apply the new interpolation function with the same current time step which means it would just snap to the new interpolation.

Instead, apply layered transitions and set varying transition delays inverted by what you want them to be when you remove the "active" class.

For example, in your style, you wanted to wait to apply the transform change until you were 25% through the animation.  Just have a transition delay set on that property.

Consider reading this article for more detail on multi-step animations: [Using Multi-Step Animations and Transitions](https://css-tricks.com/using-multi-step-animations-transitions/) .

```js
const toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");

toggle.addEventListener("click", e => {
  toggle.classList.toggle("topbar-animate-forward");
});
```

```css
.topbar-container {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1em;
}

.topbar-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.topbar-menu .topbar-navi-menu {
  margin-left: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.topbar-menu .topbar-navi-menu i {
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.topbar-menu .topbar-navi-menu i {
  transition: top 500ms ease-in-out 125ms, bottom 500ms ease-in-out 125ms, transform 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.topbar-menu .topbar-navi-menutopbar-animate-forward i {
  transition: top 500ms ease-in-out, bottom 500ms ease-in-out, transform 500ms ease-in-out 125ms;
}

.topbar-menu .topbar-navi-menu i:first-child {
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
}

.topbar-menu .topbar-navi-menu.topbar-animate-forward i:first-child {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.topbar-menu .topbar-navi-menu i:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.topbar-menu .topbar-navi-menu.topbar-animate-forward i:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.topbar-menu .topbar-navi-menu i:last-child {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
}

.topbar-menu .topbar-navi-menu.topbar-animate-forward i:last-child {
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar-container">
  <section class="topbar-menu">
    <a id="toggle" class="topbar-navi-menu">
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
    </a>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with interpolation?